# Rcpp function works on ubuntu, but does not work on windows and mac

Tags: r, rcpp

I have the following function

```
fun <- cxxfunction(
    signature(x="numeric", y="numeric",N="interger", w="numeric", p="numeric"), 
    plugin="RcppArmadillo", 
    includes=c("#include <stdlib.h>", "#include <cmath>","#include <numeric>","#include <algorithm>","#include <vector>"), 
    body='
        using namespace Rcpp;
   RNGScope scope;

        NumericVector xa(x);
        NumericVector ya(y);
        int Na = as<int>(N);
        int n_xa = xa.size(), n_ya = ya.size();
        arma::mat wa = Rcpp::as<arma::mat>(w);
        Rcpp::NumericMatrix n(p); //one column to each x[i]/y
        NumericVector limite(n_xa);
        arma::mat z(n_ya, n_xa);
        arma::mat beta(n_ya, n_xa);
        arma::colvec one(xa.begin(), xa.size());
        arma::colvec betaM(ya.begin(), ya.size());
        arma::colvec betaP(ya.begin(), ya.size());
        arma::colvec Prob(ya.begin(), ya.size());
        arma::colvec betaC(ya.begin(), ya.size());
        z.col(0) = arma::zeros<arma::mat>(n_ya, 1);
        NumericVector nV(n_ya);
        NumericVector nT(n_ya);

        int i, j, randLR;

            for (i=0; i<n_xa; i++) {
                for (j=0; j<n_ya; j++) {
                   z(j,i) = 0;  
                }
                 randLR = rand() % n_ya;
         // randonly initialize z
                 z(randLR,i)=1;
                 limite(i)  = i;
                 one(i) = 1;
            }
    // the number of ways can be produced
            beta = wa * z;
            one = beta * one;


        int k, l,l2, pos;
        NumericMatrix prob_table(n_xa, Na);
        NumericMatrix class_table(n_xa, Na);

    int oldval;
            for(k=0; k<Na; k++){

               // limite = f(limite, n_xa);
       std::random_shuffle(limite.begin(),limite.end());
               for (l=0; l<n_xa; l++) {
                   l2=limite(l);     
        // trick, where the z.col came from 
                   betaM = one - wa * z.col(l2);
           // sum delta and normalize
           Prob = betaM;
                   std::transform(Prob.begin(), Prob.end(), Prob.begin(), std::bind2nd(std::plus<double>(),1));
                   std::transform(Prob.begin(), Prob.end(), Prob.begin(), std::bind2nd(std::divides<double>(),std::accumulate(Prob.begin(), Prob.end(), 0.0)));

                   nV = n(_, l2);
                   std::transform(nV.begin(), nV.end(), nV.begin(), std::bind2nd(std::divides<double>(),std::accumulate(nV.begin(), nV.end(), 0.0)));
           // multipling the the likelihoods
                   int nP;
                   for (nP=0; nP<betaP.size(); nP++) {
                            betaP(nP) = Prob(nP)*nV(nP);
            if(z(nP, l2)==1){
                oldval = nP;
            }

        }

                       // continuing control
                       if (std::accumulate(betaP.begin(), betaP.end(), 0.0) > 0) {
                            std::transform(betaP.begin(), betaP.end(), betaP.begin(), std::bind2nd(std::divides<double>(),std::accumulate(betaP.begin(), betaP.end(), 0.0)));
                       }
                       else {
                           // std::transform(betaP.begin(), betaP.end(), betaP.begin(), std::bind2nd(std::plus<double>(),1));
                       }
                        // a way to sample according a distribution, based on rogers
          double base = ::Rf_runif(0,1);

                       std::partial_sum (betaP.begin(), betaP.end(), betaC.begin());
                      int sz = betaC.size();
                      int idx;
                      for (idx=0; idx<sz; idx++) {
                          if(betaC[idx] > base) {
                              pos = idx;
                              break;
                          }
                      }


           if(pos!=oldval){
                        one = betaM - wa * z.col(l2);
               int nP;
                           for (nP=0; nP<betaP.size(); nP++) {
                    z(nP, l2) = 0;
                        }
                        z(pos, l2) = 1;
                        one = betaM + wa * z.col(l2);
        }       

                   prob_table(l2,k) = betaP(pos);
                   pos = pos + 1;
                   class_table(l2,k) = pos;
               }
}

//      betaP = z.col(l2);
        return Rcpp::List::create( Rcpp::Named("beta")=beta, Rcpp::Named("l2")=l2,Rcpp::Named("z")=z, Rcpp::Named("oldval")=oldval, Rcpp::Named("pos")=pos, Rcpp::Named("limite")=limite, Rcpp::Named("n")=nV, Rcpp::Named("betaM")=betaM, Rcpp::Named("betaP")=betaP, Rcpp::Named("Prob")=Prob,Rcpp::Named("prob_table")=prob_table, Rcpp::Named("class_table")=class_table );
        '
)
```

In all operating systems, 64 bits, 8 gb RAM, I load the code as

```
library(inline)
source("fun.R")
```

For a small example the function runs perfectly in all systems, but when the size of the problem increases the increase in windows and mac seems to be orders of magnitude higher.

Small example that works:

```
varx <- 1:100
vary <- 1:200
w <- matrix(sample(0:1, 200^2, replace=TRUE), 200, 200)
wm <- matrix(abs(rnorm(200*100, 0.5, 0.5)), 200, 100)
system.time(conn <- fun(varx, vary, 5000, w, wm))
```

Big Example that works only on linux:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10712588/var1_teste.rda
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10712588/var2_teste.rda

```
load("var1_teste.rda")
load("var2_teste.rda")
varx <- 1:ncol(wl$wm)
vary <- 1:nrow(wl$wm)
system.time(conn <- fun(varx, vary, 5000, w, wl$wm))
```

On ubuntu it takes 30 minutes, on windows or mac it takes 2 days and don't finish, some one have a clue? Is there any difference between the operational systems?

Answer (score 6):

Did you consider testing with a smaller problem first?

Did you consider re-building one of the existing RcppArmadillo examples first to check viability on all systems you tested?

Also, with newer Rcpp release, the 'Rcpp Attributes' capabilities allow you do thing more simply.  Consider:

```
R> cppFunction('arma::mat op(arma::colvec x) { return x*x.t(); }',
+              depends="RcppArmadillo")
R> op(1:3)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    2    4    6
[3,]    3    6    9
R>
```

where I use one call and one (wrapped) line to create an Armadillo C++ function to produce an outer product of a column vector.

Comment: Hi Drik, thanks for your answer, in fact, I have tested a small example, I will add this small reproducible example in the question. For a small example the function runs perfectly in all systems, but when the size of the problem increases the increase in windows and mac seems to be orders of magnitude higher. I was just wondering if it was not some system requirement that I did not pay attention, since I just use ubuntu. I will consider read the new Rcpp release later, thanks.

Comment: The name is 'Dirk' so I happen to mistype it from time to time too.  Otherwise, I _develop_ this on Ubuntu and it is pretty widely used on all three OSs -- the error is likely in your code.

Comment: Hi Dirk, sorry for the mistype. I really don't think there is an "error", because the result of the function is correct, and the small example runs even in my virtualbox machine 32 bits windows. I just wonder if there is some specific RcppArmadillo operation that you observed be slower on windows?

Comment: Once again, start with _small_ examples, time them and then see what, if any, speed difference you observe. Linux tends to be faster, but it all depends.  And you still have not demonstrated a reproducible error.

Comment: Hi Dirk,following your advice I extend the code analysis. Using the verbose on cxxfunction I have a warning:"comparison between signed and unsigned integer" only on windows. I also broke the code into small pieces and it seems the most time consuming step for me is the matrix operation: one(1564,1) - wa(1564,1564) * z.col(l2)(1564,1). Is there a quicker way to do this operation?